# Possible Try/Catch prevents error from showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following check needs to be added to a large AngularJS application: Whenever a screen calls a specific **global** function (`a()`) to perform an operation, an `if` condition needs to be executed. If the check returns true, then everything is ok, otherwise the execution should stop and an error message (alert) should be shown to the user. This is achieved by throwing an error and decorating AngularJS's `$exceptionHandler` to catch that specific error.

Example:

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
    return function (e, st) {
        if (e instanceof MyErr) {
            alert("An error occurred");
            return;
        }
    }
});

class MyErr extends Error { /* */ }

function a() {
    if (allWell) { /* everything's good */ }
    else {
        throw new MyErr("Failure");
    }
}
```

Problem is, ~20 other modules around the application can invoke `a()`:

Screen 1:

```
// ...
a();
alert("Success");
// ...
```

Screen 2:

```
try {
    a();
} catch (e) {
    // ...
}
alert("Success");
```

As can be seen, some screens will wrap the call to `a()` in a `try`/`catch` block, while others won't. As a result, the "Failure" message gets shown when Screen 1 makes a call, but when Screen 2 makes a call, the exception gets caught by the `try`/`catch` that was set up by the caller and "Success" message gets incorrectly shown.

With or without exceptions, how can `alert("Success")` (and subsequent code) be prevented from running (since there was an error detected earlier)?

Comment: It seems like you're asking how to make `catch` not catch. But this is what `catch` does. The solution is to make your error handling consistent throughout the app. Maybe instead of throwing on error, `a` can just perform the behavior you want.

Comment: Yes, but `alert("Success")` shouldn't be executed. That's the reason an exception is being thrown - to stop further execution.

Comment: Possibly related: [Do uncatchable exceptions exist in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368862/do-uncatchable-exceptions-exist-in-javascript)

Comment: So your real problem is that the caller may catch *a*'s exception and choose to ignore it. I guess that's the caller's problem then.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Put `alert("Success");` in `a()`.

```
function a() {
    if (allWell) { /* everything's good */
         alert("Success");
    }
    else {
        throw new MyErr("Failure");
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Use *Callback* in `a()`.

```
function a(callback = function(){}) {
    if (allWell) { /* everything's good */
         callback();
    }
    else {
        throw new MyErr("Failure");
    }
}
```

Screen 1:

```
// ...
a(function(){
    alert("Success");
});

// ...
```

Screen 2:

```
try {
    a(function(){
        alert("Success");
    });
} catch (e) {
    // ...
}
```